# Read remote configs using Paramiko + CiscoConfParse

Tags: python, paramiko, ciscoconfparse

I've a script that connects to an IPAM tool via api, gets newly created vlans and then performs 'device q {vlan}' on a remote rancid server via paramiko. From this I get a dictionary of devices where the vlans are present.

Function for that is here

```
def check_rancid_for_vlan():
vlans = get_vlans()

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(rancid_host, username=username, password=password)

results = {}
for i in vlans:
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cd /var/home/configs; device q Vlan{}'.format(i))

    for line in stdout:
        if "no" not in line:
            device = line.split(":")[0]
            if i in results:
                results[device].append(i)
            else:
                results[device] = [i]

for key, val in results.iteritems():
    for i in val:
        print(key,i)

client.close()
```

This will output

```
(u'switch1', 1001)
(u'switch2', 1002)
(u'switch3', 1003)
(u'switch4', 1004)
```

I want to search each config for the vlan and print it. CiscoConfParse allows for searching an interface with

```
parse.find_objects_w_child(r"interface", vlan)
```

but is there any way to do this remotely over paramiko? Or a better solution potentially?

Comment: (1) What does the full config look like? Apparently what you're printing is not the full info where you want to search for something. (2) Have you considered looking at the source code of CiscoConfParse for insights?

Comment: Regarding: *is there any way to do this remotely over paramiko?*.  Short answer: yes.  A) ssh into the remote device with paramiko, B) capture the output of "term len 0" and "show running".  C) Format the captured config into a list of string Cisco IOS commands.  D) Parse with [CiscoConfParse](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse).  I do this all the time in ssh sessions spawned by paramiko, netmiko, scrapli, pexpect, exscript, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to copy the config directory from remote to local and perform parse there